# Blocks and memory leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

I am using the following code to asynchronously download an image and set it to an image view .

```
dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.processsmagequeue", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

           dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{

                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                [self.imageActivityIndicatorView setHidden:YES];
                [self.imageView setHidden:NO];
            });
    });
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

I am aware the blocks automatically retain all the values they reference and then release them . But can self get released in between moving to downloadQueue and then transferring back to the callerQueue ?

Comment: No, this will be fine.  self will be retained by downloadQueue, then retained by callerQueue, then released by downloadQueue, then released by callerQueue (most likely in that order).

Comment: @eddardstark If you don't use ARC, then you don't have to worry about anything like this. Retains and releases happen only when you instruct them to do so.

Comment: how about something like this .. download queue gets stuck for about 5 minutes for whatever reason . And in the midst of that self is released . Now in this case .. does download queue release self before transferring to caller queue or afterwords ? This is what is troubling me.

Comment: @H2CO3 if I am not wrong, no dispatch and CG cases will be handled by ARC.

Comment: @thoughtbreaker But there's no ARC here! Read the second comment...

Comment: @borrrden - u said most likely .. like whats the sure fire flow ?

Comment: I didn't develop it, so I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fine.

```
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{ // --> downloadQueue will add a retain on self when it's created
           dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{ // --> callerQueue will add a retain on self when it's created
                 ...
            }); // --> callerQueue will release it's retain when it gets dealloced just after returning from here
    // --> downloadQueue will release it's retain when it gets dealloced just after returning from here
    });
```

Here's how it will execute:

1. downloadQueue adds retain on self            // +1
2. downloadQueue starts executing the block     // +1
3. callerQueue adds retain on self              // +2
4. downloadQueue releases it's retain           // +1
5. callerQueue starts executing the inner block // +1
6. callerQueue releases it's retain.            // +0

So, at any time, there will be a retainCount on self. Btw, you can check even check the retain count with `-[NSObject retainCount]` at any time.

As a side note, why not use `dispatch_get_main_queue()` instead of saving callerQueue. You should *never* do UI operations on any other thread. This is just safer in case your function is called from any other thread.

Comment: `retainCount` is useless, don't call it. Good answer otherwise.

Comment: @bbum care to explain why is `retainCount` useless? Its a good debugging tool IMO.

Comment: Sure; doesn't reflect autorelease, doesn't reflect thread ownership, implementation details may make it wildly different than expected, etc...  Details here: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Answer (score 0):

First what happens: The inner block cannot capture self from the method because that method could be long gone when the inner block is created. Therefore, it captures self from the outer block. That means "self" is used as a variable in the outer block, which means the outer block captures it. So as written, self will be there when the inner block is executed.

On the other hand, you might not want that. You might not want to keep that view alive just so that the downloaded image can be stored there. In that case you write

```
_weak WhatEverType* weakSelf = self;
```

in your method, and

```
WhatEverType* strongSelf = weakSelf;
if (strongSelf != nil)
{
}
```

in the inner block. The result: That inner block doesn't keep "self" retained; self won't stay around just because it is used in the block. If it gets dealloc'ed, weakSelf is set to nil, and you check that. Instead of storing the image, you just throw it away. But once strongSelf is set to a non-nil pointer, you know it is going to stay to the end of the block.

Answer (score -2):

Its always better not to keep self inside the queue or in block. Use the following to make the 'self' a non retained object:

```
__unsafe_unretained ViewController *tempController = self;
```

and then call every objects as tempController.imageView.image and so on.